# Why can't I transfer the value of a contract to the user's wallet?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain

I am developing a game on the blockchain platform, this game is a dose game.
The scenario of the game is that a user creates a game and a contract is created, other users can see the list of games or the same contracts and join the game and play.
I want when the user created the game and no one joined his game, he can cancel the game and get back the amount of coins he deposited.
I wrote a method called cancel, but this method does not work properly and calculates the amount of gasfee too much.

This is the error I get:

[image]

This is my solidity code:

[image]

This is my Web3js code:

[image]

Comment: Is `addressWage` a contract? Cause if it is, it needs a fallback or receive function.

Answer (score 0):

If `addressWage` is a contract, it needs to have a `receive` or a `fallback` function in order to be able to receive ether balance. Simply:

```
receive() external payable {…}
```

Moreover, the transfer call needs to specify `addressWage` as payable:

```
payable(addressWage).transfer(wage)
```